# python api - shopify.Variant 404 Error

Tags: python, api, http-status-code-404, shopify

Trying to create a new Variant using the python lib.

After creating a shopify session I simply try to create a Variant instance as per the docs

```
session = shopify.Session('<My Url>')
session.token = self.provider_access_token
shopify.ShopifyResource.activate_session(session)

v=shopify.Variant(dict(price="20.00", option1="Second"))
v.save()
```

and get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/yoda/.virtualenvs/myproject/src/shopify/shopify/base.py", line 151, in     save
    return super(ShopifyResource, self).save()
  File "/Users/yoda/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyactiveresource    /activeresource.py", line 732, in save
    data=self.to_xml())
  File "/Users/yoda/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyactiveresource    /connection.py", line 313, in post
    return self._open('POST', path, headers=headers, data=data)
  File "/Users/yoda/.virtualenvs/myproject/src/shopify/shopify/base.py", line 18, in     _open
    self.response = super(ShopifyConnection, self)._open(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/yoda/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyactiveresource    /connection.py", line 258, in _open
    response = Response.from_httpresponse(self._handle_error(err))
  File "/Users/yoda/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyactiveresource    /connection.py", line 357, in _handle_error
    raise ResourceNotFound(err)
ResourceNotFound: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Any thoughts or tips? :)

Thanks
RCdH

Answer (score 3):

Product Variants must have a product_id specified when list, count, or create actions.  This can be seen in the [Product Variant API docs](http://api.shopify.com/product_variant.html#create) because the product_id is part of the URL path.  It is for this reason that a 404 error is returned from Shopify, because the path does not exist.

The [using the shopify_python_api](http://wiki.shopify.com/Using_the_shopify_python_api#Prefix_Options) page on the Shopify Wiki has a section on prefix options which you may find helpful.

In your example you just need to change the line

`v=shopify.Variant(dict(price="20.00", option1="Second"))`

to

`v=shopify.Variant(dict(price="20.00", option1="Second", product_id=product.id))`

assuming you have a product to create a variant on in the variable `product`.

Comment: Hi Dylan, thanks for the feedback. I will give that a shot.. but as part of the process i tried.. 

    p=shopify.Product(xxxxx)
    p.variants.append(v)

Which of course did not work.. so I manually need to specify the product_id always. Will update the test as directed and see what happens :)

Comment: hmmm well here is the next lot of weirdness:

Hmm seems to be a char limit on stack overflow for comments.. that sucks a bit.

Comment: v = shopify.Variant(dict(sku='test1', product_id=92048506, price="20.00"))
    v.save()

Comment: Gives:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/Users/rossc/.virtualenvs/cartvine/src/shopify/shopify/base.py", line 151, in save
    return super(ShopifyResource, self).save()
    File "/Users/rossc/.virtualenvs/cartvine/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 737, in save
    self.errors.from_xml(err.response.body)
    File "/Users/rossc/.virtualenvs/cartvine/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 88, in from_xml
    xml_string, saveroot=True)['errors']['error']
    KeyError: 'errors'

Comment: but the errors prop is empty....


    v.errors
    <pyactiveresource.activeresource.Errors object at 0x1036f7450>
    v.errors.__dict__
    {'base': variant(None), 'errors': {}}

Comment: Feel free to append text to your original post if it is too much to fit in the comments.  Alternatively you could create a gist.

Comment: When trying to add two variants in that way I was able to reproduce the problem.  I used `shopify.ShopifyResource.connection.response.body` to get the response body, which was `'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<variant>\n  <variant>Options are not unique</variant>\n</variant>\n'`.  That is a bug in shopify.  It should be `'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<errors>\n  <error>Options are not unique</error>\n</errors>\n'`.  I'll look into fixing that regression in Shopify to avoid future confusion.

Comment: I have a fix ready to deploy on Monday for the this improper errors format regression, along with a regression test to avoid this happening again.  Sorry for the confusion it has caused.

Comment: Hi Dylan, thanks for the tips and also for looking into the issue. It is great to see such turn around and I look forward to continuing with my integration! all the best!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to pass the variant's ID along with the product_id

```
# get first product
product = shopify.Product.find()[0]

# get product's first variant
variant = product.variants[0]

# pass both the product and variant ids 
v=shopify.Variant(dict(price="20.00", product_id=product.id, id=variant.id))

# finally save the variant
v.save()
```